# Is it possible to make persistent DB connection through YII framework

Tags: php, yii

I am working on a project using YII (1.1.16) framework.
Trying to make persistent database connection through YII by using below code in config/main.php file:

```
'oracle_db'=>array
    (
    'class'=>'CDbConnection',
    'connectionString'=>'oci:dbname=$sid_name',
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password,
    'emulatePrepare' => false,
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    )
```

But, its not making persistent connection.
Please help me out. 
What is missing here???

Comment: Maybe because in `connectionString` you have single quotes string where you use variable. Try to use double quotes: instead of `'oci:dbname=$sid_name'` you should have `"oci:dbname=$sid_name"`.

Comment: How and where you assign  a proper value at $id_name ??